# My ragdoll (rd) spawn multiple times when curHp drops to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

The ragdoll, when curHp is or less than 0, sometimes create multiple clones. Here's the code:

```
    public void Dmg(float damage)
    {
        curHp -= damage;
        if(curHp <= 0)
        {
            if(rd != null)
            {
                Instantiate(rd, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to create a simple script, that will spawn a ragdoll after enemy's death, but for some reason it spawns multiple clones of ragdolls

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you're calling your `Dmg` function via some projectile in an `OnCollision` or something similar you need to keep in mind that a single bullet could trigger the function multiple times.